# Is System.File.IO.Copy atomic (another process can access/read during copy)?

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

I've looked into the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx , but I cannot find anything on wether the operation is atomic or not? Atomic in the sense that another file can access/read the file while copying.

Comment: What is "atomic"? With regards to what? Locking? There is a significant number of errors that can occur while copying a file, and `Copy` will certainly not work the same in all environments.

Comment: Can another process access/read the file while I copy?

Comment: That's a good question. You should edit your question and its title to explain exactly what you mean - currently it is not clear.

Comment: `File.Copy` calls the Win32 `CopyFile` API internally.  I've not seen it documented anywhere, but it's likely that it opens the source file with `FileShare.Read`.  You can test this easily yourself it you want to be absolutely sure: open the file for reading with `FileShare.Read` in a different application, then attempt to copy it using `File.Copy`.

Comment: You can't get a warranty here, it is undocumented largely because it is not documented for the underlying OS function either.  Which cannot guarantee anything either, a foreign file system used across a network has a knack for causing surprises.   But pretty safe to assume FileShare.None is in effect since no other value makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think "atomic" is right wording for your question unless you're talking about copy as part of an *atomic transaction* (which AFAIK can't be done in .NET without P/Invoke `CopyFileTransacted`).

Well...that said...this in an **implementation detail** and given that .NET runs on different platforms then it may also be different in each one.

`File.Copy()` *historically* on Windows desktop implementation simply invokes Win32 `CopyFile`. Its behavior in this regard is...undocumented but we can inspect how handle is opened. From a quick test you can see that:

- Source file is open with `FILE_SHARE_READ`, `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.
- Target file is open with  `FILE_SHARE_READ`, `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`.

Safe assumption: **do not assume anything**, OS, media and file systems may have different rules. Also do not assume that this is stable over time.

Educate *reasonable* assumption: you may assume that source file has `FILE_SHARE_READ` and assume nothing about target file.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you inspect how the file handles were opened?

Comment: @stakx I'm a lazy guy...no WinDbg here, just a very huge file to copy and Process Monitor to check handle properties...